# javascript: apply two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply

Is there a way to apply a two-dimensional array to an object?

Like this:

```
var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject.apply(null,myArray);
```

It seems to apply only the first inner array :-/

Why is that?

Comment: The `apply` method is defined on the prototype of functions. Not objects. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, since your question was so uninformative I'm going to assume a lot of stuff. Firstly, I'm going to assume that `someObject` is a function. Next I'm going to assume that it has only one formal parameter like @Adam pointed out. So this is what I assume your code looks like:

```
function someObject(a) {
    alert(a);                   // were you expecting [[0,1],[2,3]]?
}

var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject.apply(null,myArray);
```

This is what I think you want instead:

```
function someObject() {
    alert(arguments);           // now it alerts [[0,1],[2,3]]
}

var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject.apply(null,myArray);
```

Remember, when you `apply` arguments to a function you pass it the arguments as an array. It's kind of like calling the function as follows:

```
function someObject() {
    alert(arguments);
}

var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject(myArray[0], myArray[1]);
```

Of course, it also assigns the function a custom this pointer.

**Edit:** Looking back at your code I think you might have intended to use `call` instead of `apply`. The method `call` allows you to pass the arguments to the function as separate arguments instead of an array of arguments. So your code would look:

```
function someObject(a, b) {
    alert(a);                  // now a is [[0,1],[2,3]]
    alert(b);                  // b is 5 and so on
}

var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject.call(null,myArray,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You code works..

With that code you pass two arguments to the someObject function, [0,1] and [2,3]

According to this fiddle that is exactly what happens.
http://jsfiddle.net/BgVxQ/

Edit: If you have an unknown number of arguments, use the *arguments* variable available inside the function to get hold of them. If you have a fixed number of arguments, then it's often easier to declare them

```
function someObject(parameter1, parameter2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

That way you don't need to manually extract them from *arguments*

Answer (score -2):

```
var myArray = [[0,1],[2,3]];
someObject.apply(null,[myArray]);
```

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense because `myArray` is already an array. Also the OP wants to pass the inner arrays as arguments and not the outer array.

Answer (score -2):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), `apply` takes an array of arguments and passes them to your function.  So, you need to place `myArray` inside an array that will be unpacked to form the argument to `someObject`:

```
var myArray = [[0, 1],[2, 3]];
someObject.apply(null, [myArray]);
```

In the code you posted, the function `someObject` was receiving two arguments: `[0, 1]` and `[2, 3]`.  This is legal because JavaScript allows functions to be called with a number of arguments that differs from the number of formal parameters.  But because there were *more* arguments than formal parameters, the second argument (`[2, 3]`) was lost and you only saw the first (`[0, 1]`).

Comment: JavaScript doesn't __lose__ any arguments. What you're trying to say is that the function `someObject` has only one named parameter and hence only `[0, 1]` can be accessed. That is wrong. You can use the free variable `arguments` in the function to access all the values passed to the function regardless of the function prototype.

Comment: @ZachWeyman if that "works like a charm", you are likely using only one named parameter in your someObject function, see the edit of my answer above. You probably should be using the _arguments_ variable